# Order of after_commit callbacks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

Model `Item` has an `after_commit` callback called say `updated_related`

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit :updated_related        
    def updated_related
      # update related items based on latest item
    end
end
```

also, an Observer called `ItemObserver` that has an `after_commit` called say `clear_item_cache`

```
class ItemObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    def after_commit
      #clear item from cache
    end
end
```

The trouble now is `update_related` is being called first before the observer is called and hence related items are being called on stale `item` entry.

How would I ensure that the observer's callbacks are called first since it's part of the `item` after which I would like to run the related items to run?

P.S. Removing the code from observer callbacks or remove callbacks altogether isn't an option right now.
I'm on rails 4 and using the `rails-observable` gem for Observable.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make the observer's callbacks are called first, from the [doc](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers):

> callbacks in an observer **will always be called after callbacks
>   defined in the model** itself.

You should move all logics of `updated_related` method into `after_commit` of observer, then you can control whatever order you want.

Or you can exchange code between `updated_related` and `after_commit`